# Show the number of points

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table called wp_points created in Wordpress with these fields:

`point_ID (INT)` example: 1
`point_user_ID (INT)` example: 1
`point_accumulated (INT)`

And I need to show the amount of points have any ID. I have this code but does not show me anything:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 

$milink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->points WHERE point_user_ID = 1");
echo $milink->point_accumulated; 
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried `FROM".$wpdb->points." Where...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the table:

```
$milink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM `wp_points` WHERE point_user_ID = 1");
```

if you wanted to find the SUM of points where the point_user_id equals a particular number, then you could use SUM(), although I don't know what column you are savings your points in, so in the example I'll just use `points`:

```
$milink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT SUM(points) as points_accumulated FROM `wp_points` WHERE point_user_ID = 1");
echo $milink->points_accumulated;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 

$milink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->points} WHERE point_user_ID = 1");
echo $milink->point_accumulated; 

?>
```